# What is the syntax to store a Class as a value in a Dictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift, gamekit, gameplay-kit

Lets say I want to do this:

```
class foobar : NSObject {
//method declarations, etc.
}
```

Then later:

```
let myDictionary:Dictionary = ["returnMeAnAwesomeClass":foobar]
```

Does not work.

If I put in `foobar.Type`, it also doesn't work.

If I put in `foobar.class` as `foobar.Type`, it also doesn't work.

The reason I want this is because there's a method in a system API that takes a class as the argument, e.g.:

```
func enterState(_ stateClass: AnyClass) -> Bool
```

(in GKStateMachine)

I'd find it acceptable to be able to get a string and turn that into a class.

Comment: Then try `NSClassFromString`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `foobar.self` if you need to obtain the class type. And also you should add type safety to your dictionary:

```
let myDictionary: [String:AnyClass] = ["returnMeAnAwesomeClass": foobar.self]
```

If you're initializing the dictionary at the same place where you're declaring it, you can skip the type declaration, as the compiler will infer it:

```
let myDictionary = ["returnMeAnAwesomeClass": foobar.self]
```

Comment: Does not work. That was the first thing I tried... will post you the error message when I am back at the computer. .. Maybe it's because I'm in the Playground?

Comment: Turns out you were right. The problem was that I was trying to use Array as the key type. Doesn't work. But when I used NSArray as the key type, it works. So: `let myDictionary: [NSArray:AnyClass] = ["route","to","class":customGKState.self]` etc. etc. it works fine. It also helps if the class that you are referring to (like foobar.self) is ABOVE where you are in the code.